# How to compare a range of two numbers in a single row with a number in the same row?

Tags: r, comparison

I have three columns, one is the minimum price for a product, another is a maximum price for the product, and the actual price for a product. I'm trying to go row by row and compare the minimum and maximum price with the actual price to see if it is within that range.

Here is some sample data:

```
MinimumPrice    MaximumPrice    ActualPrice
30.5               41                51
95.5              100                92
45.5              50                 43
70                75                 80
```

I tried to use:

```
TBAcomparison$withinRange_Price<- ifelse(sapply(Prices$ActualPrice, function(p) 
  any(Prices$MaximumPrice <= p & Prices$MinimumPrice>= p)),1, NA)
```

Although, this isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

The result should be:

```
MinimumPrice    MaximumPrice    ActualPrice      WithinRange
30.5               41                51             1
95.5              100                92             NA
42.5              50                 43             1
70                75                 80             NA
```

Anyone able to assist would be much appreciated.

dput:

```
structure(list(MinimumPrice = c(30.5, 95.5, 45.5, 70), MaximumPrice = c(41, 
100, 50, 75), ActualPrice = c(51, 92, 43, 80), withinrange = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
Prices %>%
   mutate(withinRange_Price = case_when(ActualPrice > MinimumPrice & 
             ActualPrice <= MaximumPrice ~ 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

`<` and `>` are vectorized, so you're overcomplicating by using `sapply`. Try this:

```
Prices$withinRange_Price <- with(Prices, ifelse(MinimumPrice <= AcutalPrice & ActualPrice <= MaximumPrice, 1, NA))
```

I'm a bit confused that your code seems to use 2 data frames, but your text and sample data only indicate 1 data frame, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: For more complicated operations, in the future, you can use `dplyr::case_when()`.
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html